# Why Pandas .divide() method adding the divisor as a column with NAN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to divide a Pandas timeseries data frame with another data frame with exact matching datetime index, using pandas' `.divide()` method. When I do so instead of the expected element wise division, the divisor column is getting as a column the data frame being divided with NAN values. Why is that? I am unable to figure out.

Please note that if I use a scalar to divide there is no problem. Appreciate inputs.

Below are the info of the data frames.

```
print(week1_range)
            Max TemperatureF  Min TemperatureF
Date                                          
2013-07-01                79                66
2013-07-02                84                66
2013-07-03                86                71
2013-07-04                86                70
2013-07-05                86                69
2013-07-06                89                70
2013-07-07                77                70
-----------------------------------------
print(week1_range.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 7 entries, 2013-07-01 to 2013-07-07
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------            --------------  -----
 0   Max TemperatureF  7 non-null      int64
 1   Min TemperatureF  7 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 168.0 bytes
None
-----------------------------------------------
print(week1_mean)
           Mean TemperatureF
Date                         
2013-07-01                 72
2013-07-02                 74
2013-07-03                 78
2013-07-04                 77
2013-07-05                 76
2013-07-06                 78
2013-07-07                 72
----------------------------------------------------
print(week1_mean.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 7 entries, 2013-07-01 to 2013-07-07
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------             --------------  -----
 0   Mean TemperatureF  7 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 112.0 bytes
None
-------------------------------------------
print(week1_range.divide(week1_mean, axis='rows'))
            Max TemperatureF  Mean TemperatureF  Min TemperatureF
Date                                                             
2013-07-01               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-02               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-03               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-04               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-05               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-06               NaN                NaN               NaN
2013-07-07               NaN                NaN               NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're dividing two dataframes with differents columns names.

You need to [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) the second dataframe so pandas does not try/need *to align the columns* :

```
out = week1_range.div(week1_mean.squeeze(), axis='rows')

#or simply select the column
#out = week1_range.div(week1_mean['Mean TemperatureF'], axis='rows')

#or use to_numpy() as per @Corralien
#out = week1_range.div(week1_mean.to_numpy(), axis='rows')
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

            Max TemperatureF  Min TemperatureF
Date                                          
2013-07-01          1.097222          0.916667
2013-07-02          1.135135          0.891892
2013-07-03          1.102564          0.910256
2013-07-04          1.116883          0.909091
2013-07-05          1.131579          0.907895
2013-07-06          1.141026          0.897436
2013-07-07          1.069444          0.972222
```

Comment: You can also use `.values` (or to `.to_numpy()`) to have a vector without name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. But wondering where can I find that documentation where it tells .squeeze() needs to be applied for such situations.

Comment: @Srinivas. `squeeze()` is to transform a DataFrame of 1 column to a Series or convert a Series of 1 value to a scalar value. Generally, you use a Series to divide all columns by a vector not a DataFrame of one column.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Corralien. What you suggested seems more intuitive. Great. Just to note, Pandas .div documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html only says to match on index, which I did so.